# Knockout Js: how does the SORT function for an observable array work

Tags: knockout.js

I want so sort out an observable array with knockout sort method, but according to the documentation two fields are passed.

```
myObservableArray.sort(function (left, right) { return left.lastName == right.lastName ? 0 : (left.lastName < right.lastName ? -1 : 1) })
```

Where is the left and right parameter gotten from, do I pass them in and if i have an array like this

```
var dummyArray = [{letter: a, number: 4},{letter: f, number: 3},{letter: t, number: 2},{letter: v, number: 7},{letter: c, number: 9},]
```

how would i sort this?

Comment: _do I pass them in_. no, the sort function will do that. Sorting requires _comparing_ two values. So you need to provide the function that does the comparison

Comment: _how would i sort this?_ How would you like to sort it? By `letter`? By `number`? By one then the other? Provide the function that will return whether `left` is before or after `right` to the `sort` function

Comment: @MattBurland by number, i want an example so i could be able to understand and   work on a more complex example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*do I pass them in*:

No, the sort function will do that. Sorting requires comparing two values. So you need to provide the function that does the comparison

*how would i sort this?*:

Depends on how you want to sort them. By `letter`? By `number`? By one and then the other? By something else? You have to provide the function that does it.

So for sorting by `number` ascending:

```js
var dummyArray = [{letter: "a", number: 4},{letter: "f", number: 3},{letter: "t", number: 2},{letter: "v", number: 7},{letter: "c", number: 9}];

var koArray = ko.observableArray(dummyArray);

koArray.sort(function(l,r) { return l.number === r.number ? 0 : l.number < r.number ? -1 : 1; });

console.log(koArray())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

As the description in the Knockout docs tells you:

> Your function should accept any two objects from the array and return a negative value if the first argument is smaller, a positive value is the second is smaller, or zero to treat them as equal.

This is the same behavior as [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)